# Unexpectedly got error while inserting data

Tags: oracle11g, insert, database-trigger

when i executed the following statements i got some error.

```
CREATE TABLE TEST_TRG1(NAME VARCHAR2(50),DOB DATE);--table created successfully
CREATE TABLE TEST_TRG2(NAME VARCHAR2(50),DOB DATE);--table created successfully
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TR_TEST_TRG1
AFTER INSERT
ON
TEST_TRG1
REFERENCING NEW AS NEW OLD AS OLD
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
BEGIN

INSERT INTO TEST_TRG2 (NAME,DOB) VALUES (:NEW.NAME,:NEW.DOB);

END TR_TEST_TRG1;
/--trigger created successfully
ALTER TRIGGER TR_TEST_TRG1 ENABLE;--trigger enabled successfully
INSERT INTO TEST_TRG1(NAME,DOB) VALUES('1',SYSDATE-4);--got error at this statement
INSERT INTO TEST_TRG1(NAME,DOB) VALUES('2',SYSDATE-3);
INSERT INTO TEST_TRG1(NAME,DOB) VALUES('3',SYSDATE-2);

/
```

error was

[image]

thanks in advance

edit:

table confirmation
[image]

executed show errors trigger

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I do not know what the error is (I ran your script and got no errors) but to find out, in SQL Plus type this:

```
show error trigger TEST_TRG1
```

Comment: please look the question